# How can I make maven deploy artifacts to the home directory on a remote server without specifying it?

Tags: maven, scp

I'm able to deploy my project to my remote server like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-ssh-external</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>internal</id>
            <url>scpexe://maven@myserver.com/home/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

But (as you can see) I'm forced to specify the home directory of the `maven` user on my server. Usually when I use `scp` I can simply use `scp somefile.txt me@myserver.com:` and the file is transferred to the **home** directory of the user on my server. But if I try something similar in the `pom.xml`:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>internal</id>
        <url>scpexe://maven@myserver.com:</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

I get this error message:

```
Execution default-deploy of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy failed: For input string: "" -> [Help 1]
```

If I try this:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>internal</id>
        <url>scpexe://maven@myserver.com</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

then Maven tries creating the repo structure and deploying the artifact directly to the server root directory. So I get this error message:

```
Error executing command for transfer: Exit code 1 - mkdir: cannot create directory ‘//com’: Permission denied -> [Help 1]
```

Is there a way to specify the maven repository as residing in the users home directory without having to manually specify where the home directory is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maven configuration file uses a different syntax. What your example shows is this

```
<url>scpexe://maven@myserver.com/home/maven</url>
```

So by extension what you want is this

```
<url>scpexe://maven@myserver.com/</url>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `$HOME` environment variable like so

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>internal</id>
        <url>scpexe://maven@myserver.com:$HOME</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

OR if that doesn't work maybe this might?

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>internal</id>
        <url>scpexe://maven@myserver.com:~</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Of course this is assuming you're running Linux as well.

Comment: Getting this (same as in my question) `Execution default-deploy of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy failed: For input string: "$HOME" -> [Help 1]`. Same goes for `~`

Comment: Looks like it doesn't recognize Environment variables then. I was hoping that the path would get passed to the actual box, but I guess that isn't the case. I'm sorry, I'm not sure what else you could pass in at this point :(

Answer (score -1):

you must add port number before $HOME

```
<url>scpexe://maven@myserver.com:22/$HOME</url>
```